# How to use MS Access SQL subquery in WHERE clause to replace long OR expressions

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I'm trying to extract time log records for interesting projects, like so:

```
SELECT project, hours, date
FROM timelog
WHERE (project="one" or project="two" ... 20 more OR clauses)
```

But since I have a table containing the interesting projects, I want to say

```
SELECT project, hours, date
FROM timelog
WHERE project in (select project from InterestingProjects)
```

Unfortunately for me, I have had nothing but abject failure trying to do this on MS Access. The subquery seems to return only a few interesting projects, almost like only the first one starting with c, the first one starting with s, etc.

Am I trying to do the impossible? (Then I want to group and sum the rows by interesting project, but that's a second step, I think.) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I see anything wrong with your query, but given your last comment, I think using a `join` would make better sense:

```
select t.project, t.hours, t.date, count(ip.*) projectcount
from timelog t
   join interestingprojects ip on t.project = ip.project
group by t.project, t.hours, t.date
```

If your query isn't returning your expected results, can you verify the `project` in `interestingprojects` is the same as the `project` in `timelog`.  Perhaps check for whitespace.

Comment: Hi, your join idea was the first thing I attempted long before I posted. BUT, I was using the query-by-example screens in Access, not SQL. I also used previous working queries as a model. Some of them had two instances of the same column, one with criteria and not shown in the output, the other shown. All my attempts at using "in (select from...)" failed, and still do. Access won't accept them. After I built up Access SQL for a join "Select .. From table1 as t1 INNER JOIN table2 as t2 On t1.field = t2.field" and then converted it to the QBE screens, things worked fine. Thank you!